# CRON job not executing and returning errors

Tags: php, apache, cron

I have the following code that I am running in a cron,

```
<?php
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);
    $directory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/cron/";
    $file = "register_warranty_". date("dMY") .".csv";
    $filepath = $directory.$file;

    if(!file_exists($filepath)) 
    {
        $fp = fopen($filepath, "w+");
        fwrite($fp, "Title, Initials, Surname, HomeTel, Mobile, HouseNumber, Address, Address2, Town, Postcode, NewlyBuiltHome, InstallationDate, Houseowner, InstallersName, InstallersEmail, InstallersMobile, InstallersGasSafeNumber, BusinessName, BusinessAddress, BusinessAddress2, BusinessTown, BusinessRegion, BusinessPostcode, BusinessGasSafeNumber, BusinessEmail, SuppliersName, Model, serial, MaintenanceContract, ExpiryDate, Donotwishtobecontactedviapost, Donotwishtobecontactedviatelephone, Donotwishtobecontactedviaemail, Donotwishtobecontactedviasms\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

?>

In the Cron email I get when the cron is run - I get the following errors,

> line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
>    line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>
>    line 3:`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(**FILE**);'

Am I doing something obviously wrong, I am not the most experienced with Cron work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of 2 things:

1. Execute your PHP script from `crontab` as :

   `/usr/bin/php -q script.php`
2. Add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the start of your PHP script:

   `#!/usr/bin/php -q`

   And give execute permission to your script as:

   `chmod +x script.php`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the php command before the file name in the cronjob.

`php myscript.php`

Comment: /usr/bin/php -f myscript.php should be used instead of php myscript.php [/usr/bin/ is an example path to the execute php, to find yours.. type in shell which php]